# Adding an image to a div doesn't display unless there is content

Tags: css

If I add a background image to a div using CSS, I can't view the image until I add some content/text inside of the div.

Why is that?

Comment: Sounds like the `div` is collapsing. A `background-image` does — not — make the `div` bigger. Try with `width/height`.

Comment: You need a canvas to paint. There should be an element with some width and height to paint the background, your div is probably 0x0 when without content. You cannot see a div with 0x0 size. You can give explicit height and width in CSS along with background.

Comment: min-width something + height:auto

Comment: May also be resolved with just html with a simple `<br>` or `<p>` well placed^ If a solution doable in html use it in priority to css, for a better cross rendering with no headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because background image does not give div content.

An empty div without width/height defined will not show. A div does not have natural padding/margin so without content it has a height of 0 so you don't see it

Answer (score 0):

i will assume that the div have no height, so it will take height: 0; in case no data.
try giving it height.

Answer (score 0):

Add background-size property to div.
As background-image doesn't have height and width. Cross check your html in Developer console. You'll find that div is present.

```
background-size: 100% 200px
```